# use client.DownloadString and return to HTML again

Tags: c#, html, string, client, downloadstring

I use C# windows form app and I want to download content website and after edit it display in external browser.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string s = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
```

How can i display String html (s) in external browser?
Regard.

Comment: You can't really do that; it will have lost its origin and relative URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string s = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

If you want make it complex a little more, you can save it to a local file and open it in external browser by Process.Start() function.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string s = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("google.html");
sw.Write(s);
sw.Close();
Process.Start("google.html");
```